# Login with facebook crash the app if using FaceBook Lite

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, android-facebook

In my app I'm using facebook *SDK* to perform a login and register methods.

It's Okay when I have the general *FaceBook* application or using normal web-browser on my device.

But when I have *FaceBook Lite* on my device and I don't have the general *FaceBook* application, when I try to login/sign up using the facebook-sdk the app just close without any log/messages, So I can't know why this issue happened.

How can I fix that issue? - Can I skip *FaceBook Lite* app and use browser instead?

Update:

[Here is a video if I have normal facebook app, no problems.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MWAZEcxH0iWqByNMh39wa_z9kfYJbjgj/view?usp=sharing)

[Here is a video if I have the face book app lite on my device, which make it crash.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f-VWmpzAGr4qruzpgEAjXU7KpwsSf0O9/view?usp=sharing)

My code snippet:

```
LoginManager.getInstance()
                    .logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("public_profile"));

            LoginManager.getInstance()
                    .registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                            Log.i("MainActivity", "@@@onSuccess");
                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest
                                    .newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                            (object, response) -> {
                                                Log.i("MainActivity",
                                                        "@@@response: " + response.toString());

                                                try {

                                                    ///
                                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                    ////

                                                }
                                            });

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            Log.i("MainActivity", "@@@onCancel");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                            Log.i("MainActivity", "@@@onError: " + error.getMessage());
                        }

                    });
```

Comment: "without any log/messages" are you 100% sure that there is nothing logged? Maybe it just doesn't show for your app process so double check that you have logcat set to "no filters" and see if there are any log messages at all you can post

Comment: For me, login with Facebook is also not working when Facebook lite is installed on device. Instead of crashing the application, my app just opens the dialog to login with Facebook. So I am not sure about this but, I think Facebook SDK doesn't support login using Facebook Lite app. 
As in your case may be your crash is due to some other error. Please check.

Comment: @Nainal True, it's now only show the dialog instead of navigate to facebook lite, Maybe FB team fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was getting wired behaviors in some *LOLIPOP* device the app close even before openning the *Facebook* native application, and in other devices the app close with facebook lite only, However.

I'm was using `noHistory=true` attribute on the activity so the activity deleted from stack once the dialog appear due to calling `onStop()`.

```
<activity
        android:name=".AuthActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

After removing that attribute, Now it's worked Fine!

Answer (score 5):

You know FB's motto - move fast and break things. SDK integration with native apps is one of the things that sometimes breaks.

You can force Facebook SDK to use web for login:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY)
```

Comment: Thank's it will be a prefect answer If I can use general facebook app if exist on the device, because there is a lot of users using it.

Comment: @Ibrahim Don't change the LoginBehavior becasue the deafult LoginBehavior is NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK, which will open native FB app if installed and if app is not installed it will open web dialog.

Comment: Yes, but it does not fall back in some cases resulting in users experiencing crashes and being not able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Below code working with facebook fine.
if it not find any facebook app in devide it will open webView and get data
Call following method in onCreate() or onStart() :

```
private void facebookCallback() {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    btnFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            progressDialog.setMessage("Connection Facebook...");
            progressDialog.show();

            String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
            Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                    try {
                        System.out.println("----------------------"+object.get("email").toString());
                        verifySocialAccount(object.get("email").toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Can not find email Address.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email,gender, birthday, location"); // Parámetros que pedimos a facebook
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.out.println("-------onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            System.out.println("---------onError");
            Log.v("LoginActivity", error.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Activity Code XML :

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="6">


                    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                        xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/facebookBlue"
                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        facebook:com_facebook_login_text="SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
```